# CDK: How to set the TTL of the NS record for a Route53 PublicHostedZone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

## Problem

I created a Route 53 zone with the following code:

```ts
this.apiV2Zone = new PublicHostedZone(this, "ApiV2", {
  zoneName: "api-v2.example.com"
});
```

The zone was created as expected, but I noticed the `TTL` attribute for the `NS` record was set to `172800` (2 days).
This is a bit high at the moment, because I'm just experimenting - setting the `TTL` lower won't cost me much for now.

But, how do I go about seting the `TTL` of the `NS` record with the CDK?

---

## What I've tried

I tried to force the `NS` record myself with:

```ts
let target = RecordTarget.fromValues(
  ...this.apiV2Zone.hostedZoneNameServers ?? [] );
const recordSet = new RecordSet(this, 'ApiV2Ns', {
  recordType: RecordType.NS,
  target,
  zone: this.apiV2Zone,
  deleteExisting: true,
  recordName: this.apiV2Zone.zoneName,
  ttl: cdk.Duration.minutes(10),
});
```

But that failed on deploy with:

```
 Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: InvalidChangeBatch
: [A HostedZone must contain at least one NS record for the zone itself.]
```

Also tried with `deleteExisting: false` but that failed too because it was duplicating the existing `NS` record.

---

## Workaround

Set it manually in the AWS console.  Doesn't seem to cause any change to be reported when I do a CDK `diff`.